# Select all data from talbe 1 and replacevalues from table 2 by id if exists in table2 MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

i have to talbe t1 and t2:

```
t1:                 t2:
|ID | Value |       |ID | Value |
|---|-------|       |---|-------|
| 1 | AAA   |       | 1 | AAA   |
| 2 | BBB   |       | 2 | KKK   |
| 3 | CCC   |       | 3 | ZZZ   |
| 4 | DDD   |       | 9 | QQQ   |
| 5 | EEE   |       |---|-------|       
|---|-------|

As a relust i need to get T3 that looks like this:

|ID | Value |
|---|-------|
| 1 | AAA   |
| 2 | KKK   |
| 3 | ZZZ   |
| 4 | DDD   |
| 5 | EEE   |       
|---|-------|
```

I am new to sql and the best i can get is this :

```
SELECT
    new_TT.ID,
     (SELECT value FROM SCV WHERE ID=new_TT.id)  AS value

FROM 
    T new_TT
```

but it only return me the existing values in t1.

Another solution dose what i need but it good only with small data and i need for lagre.

The solution have 2 parts:

1. create new table t3 and copy all data from t1
2. replace row in t3 where t3.id = t2.id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`coalesce()`](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/coalesce-function.php) function with `left join`

```
create table t3 as
select t1.ID, coalesce(t2.value,t1.value) as value
  from t1
  left join t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=aa764002d485a8037ac1ad582a493bdc)</kbd>

Comment: This quary return only values from table t1

Comment: Please consider the demo @user12278232 I added.

Comment: Thanks a lot ,i am sitting on this problem 2 day and you solved it like for few minutes

Comment: you're welcome @user12278232 :) Btw I missed the part creating a new table.